# Find And Replace in a TXT From CSV File

Tags: batch-file, csv, replace, find, translation

I'm trying to find words on a first column of a CSV or XLS file, and replace them with words in the second column of the CSV of XLS. I have made something like that but it doesn't work.

Can you help me? For each line, the first column in a variable called ita and the second column in a variable called eng, and then find Ita and replace Eng. As you can imagine I need to translate a web page, starting from the csv with a language for each column. My csv file structure is:

```
ita1;eng1
ita2;eng2
```

etc...

This is my wrong script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set host=%COMPUTERNAME%
echo Host: %host%
pause
for /f "tokens=1 delims=;" %%Ita in (index.csv) do (
  SET ita=%%Ita
  echo %ita%
  pause
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=;" %%eng in (index.csv) do (
    set eng=%%eng
    echo %eng
    pause
    (for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "index.txt"') do (
      set "transl=%%i"
      set "transl=!line:%ita%=%eng%!"
      echo(!line!
        endlocal
      ))>"index2.txt"
    type "index2.txt"
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in the for loops. %%Ita and %%Eng can only be a single character. Replace them with %%I and %%E.

Answer (score 1):

```
(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%a in (index.csv) do echo(%%b;%%a)>index2.txt
type index2.txt
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand where to put it. It doesn't refer to index.txt where to find and replace text.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    (for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%l in ("index.txt") do (
        set "line=%%l"
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=; usebackq" %%a in ("index.csv") do (
            set "line=!line:%%a=%%b!"
        )
        echo !line!
    )) > index2.txt
```

But this approach doesn't care of substring match.

Comment: It make my html code work bad. Do you known why? I've used a batch script to compile my photo gallery. When the script finisced it creates for a Jpg something like "file_name     .jpg"... Can be that this script make the same? How can i solve it?

Comment: No data enough to answer to it. Can you provide samples of your html, index.txt and index.csv?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `awk`

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} { for(x in a) gsub(x,a[x]) } 1' index.csv index.txt
```